# spfx React - include javascript assets in sppkg

Tags: javascript, spfx, react

I create my package with this command

> gulp clean

> gulp build --ship

> gulp package-solution --ship

in my sppkg there aren't javascript files in package, and when I deploy this in the app catalog, and use my webpart, I don't see anything and there are a lot of error of 404

Answer (score 1):

I find alone the solution :)
Add the command gulp bundle

> gulp clean

> **gulp bundle --ship**

> gulp build --ship

> gulp package-solution --ship

Comment: The ***Bundle*** action was missing.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but the **Bundle** command should come *after* the build command.